# Threads eating into CPU performance

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a console application(c#) where I have to call various third party API's and collect data. This I have to do simultaneously for different users. I am using threads for it. But as the number of users are increasing this service is eating into the CPU performance. It is affecting other processes. Is there a way we can use threads for parallel processing but do not affect the CPU performance in a huge way.

Comment: Threads are not lightweight. You could use IO Completion Ports if this is waiting on a network response, they are lighter weight and not tied to a specific thread. Or you can avoid using threads directly and instead use something like TPL. I would favour simply using TPL.

Comment: Is your CPU busy doing more work when there are more users, or is it busy managing threads? If you believe it is the latter, why do you think that?

Comment: Apart from the point @AdamHouldsworth mentions, can you give us a specific number of users? Are we talking about a transition from 1 user which peaks to 10 users, or 1000 users which peaks to 100.000 users?

Comment: Favor the ThreadPool, set Thread.Priority to a value below Normal, dedicate the machine to just the service if it is plain overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

I assume from your question that you're creating threads manually, and so the quick way to answer this is to suggest that you use an API like the [Task Parallel  Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx), because this will take an arbitrary number of tasks and try to use a sensible number of threads to process them - so given 500 API requests, it would limit itself to just a few threads.

However, to answer in more detail: the typical reason that you would see this problem is that code is creating too many threads. Threads are not free resources - they are expensive.

A **made up example** based on your question might be this:

- you have 5 3rd party APIs that you need to call, and each is going to return ~1MB of data per user
- you call each API on a separate background thread, for each user
- you have 100 users
- you therefore have created 500 threads in total, each of which is waiting on data from the network

The problem here is that there are 500 threads the program is trying to manage, and they are all waiting on the slowest piece of the system - the network.

More simply, we are trying to download 500 pieces of data at once (which in this example would mean everything finishes slowly), rather than downloading them one at a time so that individual items will finish earlier. Because each thread will be doing nothing (just waiting for the network), the CPU will switch between idle threads continually. As you increase your number of users, the number of threads increases - which increases the CPU usage just for switch between threads, even though each thread is actually downloading more slowly. This is (approximately) why you'll be seeing slower performance as your user count goes up.

A **better example** would be to take the same scenario and use just one background thread:

- you have 5 3rd party APIs that you need to call, and each is going to return ~1MB of data per user
- each API call is put into a queue and the queue is processed by a single thread
- you have 100 users
- you therefore have 1 thread running in the background which is using the full available bandwidth of the network for each request

In this example, your CPU usage will be pretty consistent - no matter how many users you have, there is only one background thread running, so context switching is minimised. Each individual API call runs at the maximum rate of the network card and so finishes as quickly as possible.

The reality is that one thread is probably not enough: a single request is unlikely to saturate the network, as there will be limiting factors elsewhere. But this is something you can tune later: maybe 2 or 3 threads would be more performant, but 4 threads would be slower again. The general rule when threading is to *start small and work up*, not to create a thread for each piece of work.

Comment: 'the CPU will switch between idle threads continually' - a somewhat misleading statement :)

Comment: True, that was a bad choice of words. You will, though, see far more context switching than is useful.

Comment: I cannot keep them in a queue and process only single thread. That way it will take a lot of time for one complete iteration to finish. Say I am binding Twitter Time Line using its API for 100 users. 100th user has to wait for 99 threads to finish for his time line to get updated. If I can process them simultaneously, there won't be that delay in fetching and showing his timeline.

Comment: No, if you process them simultaneously, then the potential worst case is that *everyone* will see that same delay. Multithreading doesn't necessarily make anything faster! you give the perfect example: if you're binding to an API and making 100 network requests, running those in parallel will *slow* the end result, not speed it. I would suggest one or two threads making API requests, and probably one thread processing the results of the requests, and then tune from there. I'd expect that creating one thread per request would ruin your performance.

Answer (score 0):

First, run a [profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) and checkout some [refactoring](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) tools to see if you can perform code optimization to resolve the issue.  If your application is still overloading the server then setup or purchase [load balancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29).  In the meantime, if you are running the latest OS's you could try setting a hacky [CPU rate limit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384148%28WS.10%29.aspx)...however, that may not work for the needs you described.